# How to get rid of project errors in Android Studio?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, error-handling

hopefully someone is able to help me with this issue i am having with Android Studio. I have recently started a project on android studio and i have bunch of errors on the console. I was hoping somebody here is able to help me sort this out. I did add firebase to my project and prior to that my app was running fine even though i still had errors in background, but now the app wont compile and the build fails every time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej9np.png)

FLUTTER DOCTOR RESULTS

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)
• Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/razikhan/Developer/AndroidStudioProject/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 77d935af4d (5 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
• Engine revision 890a5fca2e
• Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/razikhan/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 13 Pro (mobile) • 66B4D2D9-51DC-4312-8229-178591189EAF • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.71

• No issues found!

Comment: run this command `flutter clean && flutter run' also select a device to run.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work and i got the same error as before

Comment: Can you share your `flutter doctor` result?

Comment: @Fahmida I just added the result to the original question.

Comment: This is happening for the flutter_goldens package that you are using. It has some platform specific issues. Post your errors as a github issue like this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63587